# Do not update or delete data from the database

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have doman class:

```
package testgrails12
class Teams {
String name
static mapping = {
version false
}
static constraints = {
name nullable: true
}
}
```

I'm trying to delete or update data from a table In my controller:

```
def team = Teams.get(1)
team.delete()
```

Update:

```
team.name = '123'
team.save()
```

I do not get a result either in the first or in the second cases. Also I do not get any errors. I'm confused. It just does not work. I see the result in the database.

Comment: what's problem in update and delete why you not deleted and updated

Comment: @AshishShahi I do not get any errors. Functions just do not work.

Comment: @AshishShahi I think the problem is in the settings or mapping

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/jdbc-tutorial-sql-insert-select-update-and-delete-examples can You check this link

Comment: Can you show the complete controller actions and gsp code used to invoke the actions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start would be to generate the views and controller to get an idea of how 'stuff' happens between the view and controller, run the [generate-all](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html) command.

```
generate-all testgrails12.Teams
```

You'll end up with a TeamsController and all the relevant gsps.

You can also make use of [scaffolding](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/scaffolding.html) which is essentially the same as above but all the magic is hidden.
Create the following Teams controller:

```
class TeamsController {
    static scaffold = Teams
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete ->

```
   def delete(Long id) {
            def teamsInstance = Teams.get(id)
            if (!teamsInstance) {
         your logic,  if team instance is null
            }

                teamsInstance.delete(flush: true, failOnError:true)
                 }
```

update ->

```
def update(Long id {
        def teamsInstance = Teams.get(id)
         teamsInstance.setName("xyz");
teamsInstance.save(flush: true, failOnError:true)
}
```

In both action i have use flush: true, failOnError:true 
If there will any error in your domain then failOnError will throw exception, and with the help of exception you can trace the issue.

Comment: You've specified Person instead of Teams in update action

Answer (score -1):

for committing result to database use special method of session - flush()